# Having trouble with ReactJS and Bootstrap in Codepen.io

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm getting two specific errors in my project I can't figure out for the life of me.  The first one is:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique 'key'
>   prop.

The next one is as follows:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Yet I know for a fact that each element in my DOM Rendering has a key property and the `{recipe.ingredients.map()}` is defined and spelled the same everywhere.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Please find my code below.

```
class RecipeApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 0,
      recipes: [
        {
          recipeName: "Sample Recipe1",
          ingredients: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
          image:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfkpHkg_PvY3OGFI3FOO80RyvShYc6wfdsbfbMSpnEDDhzzcUJQw",
          id: "item1",
          method: "In here we have the method with which to assemble the recipe into an edible dish"
        },
        {
          recipeName: "Sample Recipe2",
          ingredients: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
          image:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRMVo-OeRcXXk-d2F7ymofbRMHBJzrXx8izKbva15aWR0l9Sf1g7A",
          id: "item2",
          method: "In here we have the method with which to assemble the recipe into an edible dish"
        },
        {
          recipeName: "Sample Recipe3",
          ingredients: ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
          image: "http://clubsinnyc.com/img/noimage.jpg",
          id: "item3",
          method: "In here we have the method with which to assemble the recipe into an edible dish"
        }
      ],
      newRecipe: { recipeName: "", ingredients: [], image: "", id: "", method: "" }
    };

    //console.log(this.state.recipes);
  }

  updateNewRecipe(recipeName, ingredients, image, method){
    this.setState({newRecipe: {recipeName: recipeName, ingredients: ingredients, image: image, method: method}})
  }

  saveNewRecipe(){
    let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
    var id = function(){
      return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    }
    recipes.push({recipeName: this.state.newRecipe.recipeName, ingredients: this.state.newRecipe.ingredients, image: this.state.newRecipe.image, id: id, method: this.state.newRecipe.method});
    localStorage.setItem("recipes", JSON.stringify(recipes));
    this.setState({recipes});
    this.setState({newRecipe: {recipeName: "", ingredients: [], image: "", method: ""}});
  }


  render() {
    var { recipes, newRecipe, currentIndex } = this.state;
    //console.log(recipes);
    return (
      <div className="container w3-card">
        <div>
          {recipes.map((recipe, index) => (
            <div className="panel-group w3-margin" id="accordion">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading" eventkey={index} key={index}>
                  <h2 className="text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={"#" + recipe.id}>{recipe.recipeName}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-collapse collapse row" id={recipe.id}>
                  <div className="panel-body">
                    <ol className="list-group pull-left col-md-5 w3-margin">
                      {recipe.ingredients.map((item) => (
                        <li className="list-group-item" key={item}>{item}</li>
                      ))}
                    </ol>
                    <div className="pull-right img-responsive col-md-7" id="image">
                      <img className="thumbnail" src={recipe.image} alt="recipe-image" id="image" key={index} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="container-fluid w3-card pull-left col-md-12" id="method" key={index}>
                      {recipe.method}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          <div className="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" id="newModal">
            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header w3-black">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title text-center">Add Recipe</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <div className="control-label">Recipe Name</div>
                      <input 
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        value={recipes.recipeName}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(event.target.value, newRecipe.ingredients, newRecipe.image, newRecipe.method)}
                        placeholder="Please Enter Recipe Name..."
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <div className="pull-left">List Ingredients:</div><br/>
                      <textarea 
                        className="pull-left"
                        type="textarea"
                        value={recipes.ingredients}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(newRecipe.recipeName, event.target.value.split(","), newRecipe.image, newRecipe.method)}
                        placeholder="Please list the ingredients [Seperated by commas]"
                      />
                      <div className="pull-right">Image Link:</div><br/>
                      <input
                        className="pull-right"
                        type="text"
                        value={recipes.image}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(newRecipe.recipeName, newRecipe.ingredients, event.target.value, newRecipe.method)}
                        placeholder="Supply a link to an image."
                      />
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <div className="control-label">Method:</div>
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control"
                        type="textarea"
                        value={recipes.method}
                        onChange={(event) => this.updateNewRecipe(newRecipe.recipeName, newRecipe.ingrediets, newRecipe.image, event.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Enter recipe method here..."
                      />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={(event) => this.saveNewRecipe()}>Save Recipe</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg w3-margin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal">New Recipe</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RecipeApp />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Comment: PS.  The second error only occurs when I click the save button in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you weren't binding your functions properly. For example, `saveNewRecipe`. You can bind your function easily like so:

```
saveNewRecipe = () => {}
```

I've fixed it for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjp6npx14v

Comment: Sorry, for whatever reason that was showing an old version of the code. Try the link again.

Comment: Thanks @Colin, that takes care of the 2nd error, the only problem now though is that the function isn't doing what it's supposed to.  You see it's supposed to pull the updated data from the newRecipe object, convert it to JSON format and add it to the recipes object in the state which is then mapped and displayed in the DOM.  Plus the input fields in the modal isn't clearing so I suspect the function isn't firing at all.

Comment: Check it now, should be fine. The `<button>` should have: `onClick={this.saveNewRecipe}`